# Building on Many Core Systems in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I recently (massively?) upgraded my system from a (circa 2010) Core i7 980x with 12 GB of Ram to a Dual dodeca-core system with hyperthreading (2x12x2) with 128GB of Ram.

On Visual Studio's end, I rarely see it go beyond 6% utilization (3 cores) during build.  Does anyone here know what the caveats to its build pipeline are: does it just have one core per project, does it distribute a single project across multiple cores, or is there something I'm missing?

I'm currently using Visual Studio 2013 and have shelved the 2015 upgrade until ... I *recover* from the system upgrade :)

On the note above, does Visual Studio 2015 see improved performance on distributing its workload due to the Roslyn pipeline, or is it still using the preexisting MSBuild architecture?

Comment: Not sure what the discussion of _TPL_ has to do with _Visual Studio concurrent build_. To change how many cores Visual Studio will use during compilation of a .NET solution, check out **Tools.Options.Projects and Solutions.Build and Run** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0xettzf(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: I've already set this to 48, which was incorrectly set to 32 by default on this new machine. I suspect it has to do with Environment.ProcessorCount which reports this value incorrectly.  Changing the value didn't improve anything, which makes me think there's something else going on here, hence the question.  I'll edit on the other points.

Comment: Thanks. _How many_ projects are in your solution and how _coupled_ are they? Are they all c#?

Comment: On the project in question, 14, highly and all C#.  Which probably would implicitly answer my question.  Headaches tend to impair logical thought a bit.  Sometimes the obvious answer *is* the correct one.

Comment: Glad to have been some small help.  Sometimes it's useful just talking/writing about it to someone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP:

> *Does anyone here know what the caveats to its build pipeline are: does it just have one core per project, does it distribute a single project across multiple cores, or is there something I'm missing?*

To change how many cores Visual Studio will use during compilation of a .NET solution, check out **Tools.Options.Projects and Solutions.Build and Run** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0xettzf(v=vs.90).aspx.

MSDN:

> *1. In the Visual Studio IDE, on the **Tools** menu, click **Options**.
>   The Options Dialog Box will appear.*
>
> *2. Expand the **Projects and Solutions** folder, and then select the **Build and Run** property page.*
>   *3. Enter an integer in the text box for the **Maximum number of parallel project builds** property. The highest value that you can set this property is 32.*

Having said that actual results will vary depending on how many projects are independent vs projects that depend on other projects to be built first.  **If you have many dependencies, you may not notice much gain.**

OP:

> I've already set this to 48, which was incorrectly set to 32 by default on this new machine

**EDIT:** OP has indicated that the number of logical cores is 48.

Generally, setting this value to inordinately large values has no benefit:

MSDN:

> ***Build performance does not increase** when you set the **Maximum number of parallel project builds** property to a **value greater than the number of CPUs on your computer**.* https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0xettzf(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: The number of logical cores on the system is 48, and I didn't notice the max limit on the MSDN article.  Thanks for that.  I've also removed the TPL points because they were not relevant.

Comment: 48! I at first read I read it has "dual core" for some silly reason.  My bad.  Enjoy you new computer good sir :)

Comment: Yeah, it's for a highly threaded workload that eats RAM.  I couldn't continue on it with the setup I had.  I solved the memory issue after I purchased the system, which also improved performance a bit, but I still had cases where there were 2+hour run-times which the new system quickly ate through and showed I had a few concurrency issues that twelve cores weren't enough to hit frequently.